# Meaning of 業務執行社員

Tags: meaning, words

I would like to know which is the meaning of 業務執行社員／業務を執行する社員 (company employee who executes business operations). How do these words differ from just 社員?

May 業務執行社員／業務を執行する社員 refer to "a representative, a proxy", that is, a company employee who represent the company and is authorised to act in its name?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word 社員 lit. "firm member" is ambiguous in Japanese. In everyday language, it normally means "company staff(s)" or "employee" (= 従業員). In legal terms, however, it means those who has right to participate in a legally established organization, that is, for a usual joint-stock company, shareholders.

Thus 業務執行社員 (as a technical term) means a shareholder who executes the company's business. It is a legal concept (that the director board can delegate such-and-such to them...), and usually not used as a public title such as 社長, 取締役, 役員, CEO etc.

Answer (score 0):

It must be 常務（執行役員） instead of 業務（執行役員）, literally nobody says 業務執行役員 and it does not make sense at all. 常務執行役員 is the name of title which is unique to Japanese culture. The definition is that this person is a board member but only responsible for execution, management is out of his or her responsibility.
There are many titles in Japanese "サラリーマン" culture but mostly 会長、社長、副社長、専務、常務、部長、課長 are the common titles. Depends on companies, the variety of tiles vary but these are the most common ones.